# I can not install Angular Flex

Tags: angular, npm, flexbox

I have an error when I run **npm install @angular/flex-layout**. Anyone knows what does it mean?
I try --force, then the installation is complete successfully, but when I start up the project, it is broken

```
gonzalo@gonzalo-Inspiron-15-3567:~/Desktop/Programacion-Verdadero/Angular/05 - heroesApp$ npm install @angular/flex-layout
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: heroes-app@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/cdk@11.2.13
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/cdk
npm ERR!   @angular/cdk@"^11.2.13" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/cdk@"^14.0.0" from @angular/flex-layout@14.0.0-beta.41
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/flex-layout
npm ERR!   @angular/flex-layout@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /home/gonzalo/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/gonzalo/.npm/_logs/2022-12-29T16_35_53_034Z-debug-0.log
```

**Adding package.json according my configuration**

```
{
  "name": "heroes-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~11.0.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.2.13",
    "@angular/common": "~11.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.0.1",
    "@angular/core": "~11.0.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.0.1",
    "@angular/material": "^11.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.0.1",
    "@angular/router": "~11.0.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1100.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~11.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.0.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Since you seem to use Angular 11, you probably have to install an earlier version of `@angular/flex-layout`. Maybe you can try `npm install @angular/flex-layout@11.0.0-beta.33`

Comment: I try @kellermat! This is the new error: While resolving: @angular/material@11.0.3
npm ERR! Found: @angular/cdk@11.2.13
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/cdk
npm ERR!   @angular/cdk@"^11.2.13" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular/cdk@"^11.0.0" from @angular/flex-layout@11.0.0-beta.33
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/flex-layout

Comment: Can you list the dependencies according to `package.json` in your post?

Comment: @kellermat of course! Done!

Comment: I created an Angular project with exactly your dependency-configuration... and it worked! Maybe you can try the following: 1.) Delete the folder 'node_modules' (you can do it manually or use `rm -rf node_modules/*` for this), 2.) execute `npm install --force` (--force will recreate package-lock.json). 3.) run `npm start` and see if it works now.

Comment: nothing @kellermat! It is rare...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I face this problem,
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFmw3.png)

see the solution.

npm remove  @angular/cdk

npm install --save @angular/flex-layout @angular/cdk --force